# How to pass arguments to C++ `std::thread`

Tags: c++, multithreading

How should I pass arguments to the `std::thread`s that I create? I wrote a very simple code which involves two threads: `t1` and `t2`. The code tries to increment a shared counter variable which is passed by reference to the the two threads. To ensure that there are no race conditions, I also pass a `std::mutex` by reference to the threads which is used to access the shared count variable. My code is shown below:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

void compute(std::mutex& m, int& count)
{
        std::cout << "Hi from thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        m.lock();
        count++;
        m.unlock();
}

int main()
{
        volatile int count = 0;
        std::mutex m;
        std::cout << "Launching Threads..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "count = " << count << std::endl;
        std::thread t1(compute, m, count);
        std::thread t2(compute, m, count);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        std::cout << "Exiting..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "count = " << count << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile my code using `g++ main.cc`, I get:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/thread:43,
                 from main.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h: In instantiation of ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(std::mutex&, int&); _Args = {std::mutex&, volatile int&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’:
main.cc:19:41:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:130:72: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  130 |                                       typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                                                        ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:130:72: note: ‘std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value’ evaluates to false
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::mutex&, int&), std::mutex, int> >’:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:203:13:   required from ‘struct std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::mutex&, int&), std::mutex, int> > >’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:143:29:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(std::mutex&, int&); _Args = {std::mutex&, volatile int&}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’
main.cc:19:41:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:258:11: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::mutex&, int&), std::mutex, int> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(std::mutex&, int&), std::mutex, int> >’
  258 |           _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:262:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(std::mutex&, int&), std::mutex, int> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(std::mutex&, int&), std::mutex, int> >’
  262 |         operator()()
      |         ^~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why is `count` `volatile` in main?  Your `compute` function is expecting a count that is **not** `volatile`.  And nothing in your code suggests that the variable should be `volatile`.

Comment: `volatile` is inappropriate here. `std::thread t1(compute, std::ref(m), std::ref(count));`. Though it's easier with lambdas: `std::thread t1([&]{ compute(m, count); });`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I removed volatile and added `std::ref` which solved the problem. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Side note: It doesn't take much to accidentally skip a manual unlock, so avoid manual locking and unlocking of a mutex in favour of a RAII mechanism like [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock).

Comment: Ditto what @Artyer said. IMO, the cleanest way to construct a `std::thread` is not to pass a function pointer and arguments, but to pass a _function object_ that incorporates the arguments. The lambda expression in @Artyer's comment constructs a function object that _captures_ a reference to the `count` variable. IMO, when properly formatted, it's much easier to read than that `...std::ref(...)...` business.